# Does SessionStatus object.setComplete() clears all the session attributes or just work for the controller in which it is used?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I am not clear about this if I use SessionStatus object.setComplete() in a Controller, does it clears all the session data of the Webapp or just clears the session data saved by 
a particular controller in which @SessionAttributes is used?

Comment: I will reframe it as is SessionStatus same as session.invalidate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SessionStatus#setComplete()` JavaDoc is pretty clear about the method's purpose:

```
/**
 * Mark the current handler's session processing as complete, allowing for
 * cleanup of session attributes.
 */
```

This clears the current handler's session attributes registered via `@SessionAttribute`. This is completely different from servlet's `HttpSession#invalidate()`:

```
/**
 * Invalidates this session then unbinds any objects bound to it. 
 */
```

This one actually destroys the user session completely.