# How to remove only one attribute in session java spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am trying to learn how to use session attributes, but I have a problem removing them from session.
I want to remove only one attribute from session, but using status.setComlete() removes all my attributes from session.
I have been searching how to do it:

```
status.setComplete();       
request.removeAttribute("listaMaquinasImportar", WebRequest.SCOPE_SESSION);
```

This removes all the attributes.
Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Does SessionStatus object.setComplete() clears all the session attributes or just work for the controller in which it is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038709/does-sessionstatus-object-setcomplete-clears-all-the-session-attributes-or-jus) .`status.setComplete();` will clean your session so you probably don't want to use this method.

Comment: Yes, I have tried setComplete(), but it removes all the attributes.

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue. Please accept and upvote for answers that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer.
The method `setComplete()` removes all the attributes marked with `@SessionAtributes`.
If you want to keep a session attribute, you must add it to the `HttpSession`. I wanted to keep in session the user logged, so I have added it to `HttpSession`.
All the remaining attributes are removed when you call `setComplete()`.